# How do libgnutls version numbers work?

Tags: versions, gnutls

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and it appears there are two libgnutls packages available: `libgnutls26` and `libgnutls28`.  According to `apt-cache show`, these are versions 2.12.23 and 3.2.11, respectively.  The corresponding C++ runtime packages appear to be `libgnutlsxx27` and `libgnutlsxx28`, respectively.  What do the "26", "27", and "28" in the package names mean and how do they correspond to the versions (if they do)?